# Ajax returning only new message

Tags: python, ajax, django

I've this Django app:

A page with a form at the top with one field for sending message into db, and below it the global message list.

```
<body>

<form id="messageForm" action="" method="post">
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" id="go" name="go" value="Go!">
</form>

<div id="msg_list">
    <ul id="update">
        {% for message in messages %}
        <li>{{ message }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul> 
</div>

</body>
```

When you click on submit:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#messageForm").submit(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        data = $("#id_text").val()
        dataString = "text=" + data
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/sendmsg/",
            data: dataString,
            success: function(html) {
                $("#update").html(html);
                $("ul#update li:first").hide()
                $("ul#update li:first").slideToggle("slow");
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

Every message has a text and a timestamp field (automatically added).
Actually, when you insert a new message, the process-page returns to the homepage all list of messages:

```
if form.is_valid():
     form.save()
     messages = Message.objects.all()
     render(request, 'message_list.html', {'messages': messages})
```

and this `message_list.html`

```
{% for message in messages reversed %}
<li>{{ message }}</li>
{% endfor %}
```

But when you click 'submit', others users may have sent other messages. I would returns only new message. I mean messages with a timestamp newer than timestamp of the last message that I can see in the list. I hope you get me.

How can I do this? Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you want to return a list of messages newer than the one saved by your form. You could get the timestamp from the form, and then filter messages to get only messages with a timestamp greater than the message just saved. I'm going to assume your form's timestamp field is of the forms.DateTimeField variety.

```
timestamp = form.cleaned_data['timestamp'] # get timestamp from form, 
messages = Message.objects.filter(timestamp__gt=timestamp) # return only messages newer than timestamp
```

**Edit:**
if You want only messages newer than the last post on the page, send the id of the last message and then filter on it's timestamp, the same way, for instance you could do something like:

```
last_msg = get_object_or_404(Messages, pk=form.cleaned_data['last_msg'])
messages = Message.objects.filter(timestamp__gt=last_msg.timestamp)
```

Comment: Nope, I want to return a list of messages newer than the last one that I can see in the list of messages in the page.

Comment: Then pass in the last message on the page, and filter on it's timestamp.

Comment: The form have two fields? Text message and ? Last message's id?

Comment: You can add any fields you want to your form. I suggest adding the id of the last message into your form, so you can then filter your Messages based on it's timestamp